# Trying to calculate a SUM from another column in Materialized View

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I am trying to calculate the sum of working days per month in a Oracle MV

Here is my request:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW DIM_DATE_MV
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
START WITH sysdate NEXT (TRUNC(sysdate)+1)  + 7 / 24
as SELECT
CAL.DATE_D as ID_DATE,
(CASE WHEN (
    (TRIM(TO_CHAR(CAL.DATE_D,'Day','nls_date_language=english')) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')) OR 
    (TRIM(TO_CHAR(CAL.DATE_D,'DD-MM')) IN ('01-01', '01-05', '08-05', '14-07', '15-08', '01-11', '11-11', '25-12')) OR 
    (TO_CHAR(CAL.DATE_D, 'DD-MM-YYYY') IN  (SELECT TO_CHAR(DOFF.DATE_OFF, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM ODSISIC.DAY_OFF DOFF where DOFF.IMPACT='ALL'))
           )  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as IS_WORKING_DAY,


(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(CAL.DATE_D , 'YYYY-MM') = TO_CHAR(CAL.DATE_D , 'YYYY-MM') THEN (Select SUM(IS_WORKING_DAY) from DIM_DATE_MV group by CAL.YEAR_MONTH_NUM) ELSE 0 END)
 as NB_WORKING_DAY_MONTH

FROM ODSISIC.ORACLE_CALENDAR CAL
LEFT JOIN ODSISIC.DAY_OFF DOFF
ON DOFF.DATE_OFF = CAL.DATE_D
```

IS_WORKING_DAY = 0 if it's Holidays, Weekend or Date in the table DATE_OFF which contains all holidays with a different date from year to year.

I want the SUM GROUP BY month of IS_WORKING_DAY = 1 in NB_WORKING_DAY_MONTH.

How can I calculate this SUM directly in my query rather than creating an intermediate table for my join with the DAY_OFF table ?

Thanks :)

Comment: I tried to use a intermediate table but I have this error : 
Error report -
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: My query : (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(CAL.DATE_D , 'YYYY-MM') = TO_CHAR(CAL.DATE_D , 'YYYY-MM') THEN (Select SUM(IS_WORKING_DAY) from ODSISIC.ORACLE_CALENDAR OCAL group by OCAL.YEAR_MONTH_NUM) ELSE 0 END)
 as NB_WORKING_DAY_MONTH,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking intelligently, I resolved by redoing my SQL query :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW DIM_DATE_MV
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
START WITH sysdate NEXT (TRUNC(sysdate)+1)  + 7 / 24
as SELECT
CAL.DATE_D as ID_DATE,
IS_WORKING_DAY as IS_WORKING_DAY,

A.SUM as NB_WORKING_DAY_MONTH

FROM  (SELECT SUM(IS_WORKING_DAY) as SUM, OCAL.YEAR_MONTH_NUM as ID_MONTH from ODSISIC.ORACLE_CALENDAR OCAL group by OCAL.YEAR_MONTH_NUM) A
INNER JOIN ODSISIC.ORACLE_CALENDAR CAL 
on CAL.YEAR_MONTH_NUM = A.ID_MONTH
LEFT JOIN ODSISIC.DAY_OFF DOFF
ON DOFF.DATE_OFF = CAL.DATE_D
;
```

I calculated the workdays before creating the view (which implies that my table DATE_OFF must be fed before ORACLE_CALENDAR)

I added a join to populate my table according to the id_month.

Its working fine now